# exporting excel file but it is in web page format

Tags: php, excel, export-to-excel

HI i am exporting my report in .xls format but when i try to save the file after some editing it alerts me that file type is Web Page. I want it to be in excel 97-2003 Workbook.
Following is my code

```
if($exportType == "xls")
{

    header("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=DD_Report.xls"); 
    header("Content-Description: PHP/MYSQL Generated Data"); 
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'); 

    $strMainStart   = "<table align='center' border='1' width='100%'>";
    $strMainEnd     = "</table>";
    $strRowStart    = "<tr>";
    $strRowEnd      = "</tr>";
    $strColumnStart = "<td>";
    $strColumnEnd   = "</td>";
    $strBoldStart   = "<b>";
    $strBoldClose   = "</b>";
}
```

Comment: If you want your file to be an Excel97-2003 workbook, then you need to write a genuine (BIFF format) xls file, using one of the many libraries like [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) that are available for precisely that purpose

Answer (score 2):

Your approach simply won't work: you're sending the mimetype for Excel, but sending HTML. It's not surprising that you get the message you get.

If you want to export in Excel format get a library like [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) to do it.